# Glossaries not being showed in the output PDF

Tags: texlive, glossaries, windows, texworks

I have problem getting glossary file in the output PDF. The following is the WME I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace,xargs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{extarrows} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage [pagebackref=true, colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan] {hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
% Glossaaires__________________________________________________ 

\usepackage[xindy={language=persian,codepage=utf8},toc]{glossaries}
%
\renewcommand\glsnamefont[1]{\rm #1}
%
\newglossarystyle{listdotpage}{%
    \glossarystyle{listgroup}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
      \item[\glstarget{##1}{##2}, ##5] \dotfill\space ##3}}
%
\newglossarystyle{listpagedot}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
      \item[\glstarget {##1}{##2}] \dotfill\space \rl{, ##5}##3}}
%
      \newglossarystyle{notation}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
     \item[\parbox{1.3cm}{\LTR{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}}] \hspace{5pt} ##3,\space ##5}}
%
\newcommand\bigZero{\mbox{\huge$0$}}
\newcommand\bigSigma{\mbox{\huge$\Sigma$}}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی و نمایه}

\newglossary[epx]{dicep}{epi}{epd}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
\GlsSetXdyLanguage[dicep]{english}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{dic.tex}
\renewcommand\glsdisplayfirst[4]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\gi[1]{\gls{#1}\glslink{ep#1}{}}
\newcommand\gn[1]{\glsentrytext{#1}}
\newcommand\gfirst[1]{\glsreset{#1}\gls{#1}\glslink{ep#1}{}}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}

%%%____________________________________

\begin{document}


\chapter{مقدمه}
\section{پیشگفتار}

در 
% Print Bibs & Glossaries _____________________________________________

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{}
\printglossary[style=listdotpage,type=main]
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\rm{\latinfont #1}}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\setLTR\DefaultMathsDigits}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\setRTL\AutoMathsDigits}
\printglossary[style=listpagedot,type=dicep]

\end{document}
```

And the glossary file (dic.tex):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommandx{\newgloss}[5][3, 5]{\@ifempty{#3}{\newglossaryentry{#1} {name={#2},description=\lr{#4}}} {\newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#2},description=\lr{#4},sort=#3}}
\@ifempty{#5}{\newglossaryentry{ep#1}{type=dicep,name={#4},description=\rl{#2}}} {\newglossaryentry{ep#1}{type=dicep,name={#4},description=\rl{#2},sort=#5}}}
%
\makeatother
%
\newgloss{g:wg}{گراف~وزن‌دار}{weighted graph}
\newgloss{trace}{اثر}{trace}
\newgloss{karonski}{کارنسکی}{Karo{\'n}ski}
\newgloss{thomason}{توماسن}{Thomason}
\newgloss{fariba}{فریبا}{Fariba}
\newgloss{accuracy}{دقت}{Accuracy}
\newgloss{adjacency}{ماتریس مجاورت}{Adjacency matrix}
\newgloss{affinity}{ماتریس نزدیکی}{Affinity matrix}
\newgloss{connected}{همبند}{Connected}
\newgloss{ccomponent}{مؤلفه همبندی}{Connected component}
\newgloss{geodesic}{ فاصله ژئودزیک}{Geodesic}
\newgloss{nn}{نزدیکترین همسایه k}{K-nearest neighbor}
\newgloss{sample}{نمونه}{Sample}
\newgloss{pca}{تجزیه مؤلفه های اساسی}{Principal Component Analysis}
\newgloss{sparse}{تنک}{Sparse}
\newgloss{supervised}{بانظارت}{Supervised}
\newgloss{unsupervised}{بدون‌نظارت}{Unsupervised}
\newgloss{undirected}{گراف بدون جهت}{undirected graph}
\newgloss{directed}{گراف جهت‌دار}{directed graph}
\newgloss{simplegraph}{گراف ساده}{simple graph}
\newgloss{laplacianmatrix}{ماتریس لاپلاسین}{Laplacian matrix}
\newgloss{positivesemi}{مثبت نیمه معین}{positive semidefinite}
\newgloss{weight}{ماتریس وزن}{weight matrix}
\newgloss{embedding}{فرونشاندن}{Embedding}
\newgloss{PCA}{تحلیل مؤلفه اصلی}{Principal component analysis (PCA)}
\newgloss{classification}{کلاس‌بندی}{Classification}
\newgloss{clustering}{خوشه‌بندی}{Clustering}
\newgloss{estimation}{تخمین}{Estimation}
\newgloss{prediction}{پیش‌بینی}{Prediction}
\newgloss{regression}{رگرسیون}{Regression}
\newgloss{MDS}{ مقیاس‌گذاری چندبعدی}{MultiDimensinal Scaling (MDS)}
\newgloss{lle}{نگاشت خطی محلّی}{Locally Linear Embedding (LLE)}
\newgloss{le}{نگاشت ویژه لاپلاسی}{Laplacian Eigenmap}
\newgloss{isomap}{نگاشت هم‌اندازه}{Isomap}
\newgloss{sle}{نگاشت ویژه لاپلاسی نظارت یافته}{Supervised Laplacian Eigenmap}
\newgloss{tail}{دُم}{tail}
\newgloss{head}{سر}{head}
\newgloss{sconnected}{قویاً همبند}{strongly connected}
\newgloss{semisupervised}{ نیمه نظارتی}{semi-supervised}
\newgloss{similarity}{ماتریس شباهت}{similarity matrix}
\newgloss{rank}{رتبه}{rank}
\newgloss{orthonormal}{متعامد~نرمال}{orthonormal}
\newgloss{overcomplete}{فراکامل}{overcomplete}
```

What is wrong with it?

I've read a few questions regarding the issue (glossaries not being printed) but some of them address using `\printglossary` command and the others with `\makeglossaries` do not work for me. I tried compiling the document with `MakeIndex`but to no avail (get error Couldn't find input index file xxxxx nor xxxxx.idx.)

Comment: Try running the `makeglossaries` tool with `xxxxx` as parameter at the command line. Alternatively, running `makeindex` with the automatically created `.glo` file should work too.

Comment: @siracusa Could you please elaborate on how to run `MakeIndex` with the automatically created .go file?

Comment: The command `\makeglossaries` should create files called `xxx.glo` and `xxx.ist` (if `xxx.tex` is your LaTeX file). You now run the command `makeindex xxx.glo -s xxx.ist -o xxx.gls`, which should create a file `xxx.gls` if no errors occur, and after that you compile your LaTeX file again. That should give you the glossary in the final output. Please refer to the `glossaries` documentation for more details.

Comment: You've used the `xindy` option which means the glossary files must be processed by `xindy` not by `makeindex`.

Comment: @siracusa No, that doesn't work and there is no glossary in the output file.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I get this error: *** - PROGN: variable LANG/GENERAL/LATIN9-LANG.XDY has no value

C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:679: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl xxxxx.glo

Comment: Did you use `makeglossaries` or did you explicitly call `xindy`? If you called `xindy` directly, you probably need to include `-C variant1-utf8` or something similar.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should be loaded LAST with a few notable exceptions. Also `\rm` and friends are 20+ years out of date and ought not be used in documents designed for LaTeX 2e (as opposed to LaTeX 2.09 or current versions of other formats).